# java.lang.NullPointerException CheckBox.isChecked();

Tags: android

I got a `NullPointerException` error with this.

```
if(Cb_Ar.isChecked())
        toPass = Cb_Ar.toString();
    else if (Cb_Db.isChecked())
        toPass = Cb_Db.toString();
    else if (Cb_Hb.isChecked())
        toPass = Cb_Hb.toString();
```

Here is my LogCat;

```
03-06 20:38:54.907 3274-3274/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null object reference

03-06 20:38:54.907 3274-3274/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.jello.letscook.showmenu.showList(showmenu.java:73)

03-06 20:38:54.907 3274-3274/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.jello.letscook.showmenu.onCreate(showmenu.java:46)

03-06 20:38:54.907 3274-3274/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
```

Comment: Your `Cb_Ar` is null - check the "duplicate" link.

Comment: Your are converting a null into string which causes error

Comment: How to get the value text of Checkbox ?

Comment: use getText() method -> Cb_Ar.getText()